# How to get next and previous five element of from an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an array which consist n element.

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

and also have two button ***next and prev*** and initially i am showing the first 5 element(on page load) of an array **initial array [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]**

how i can show the next five elements on the **next button click [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]** and on **previous button click want to show the [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]**

and also need to check the if it does not have any next element if lastIndex is included and if array includes first element.

i have tried using slice to arr.slice(begin[, end])

Comment: Are you able to share what you've tried/done so far as a minimal example ([mre]) so that we have a base to go off of?

Comment: Keep track of a `pageNr`. Current page is always `arr.slice(pageNr * 5, pageNr * 5 + 5)`. Prev button is disabled if `pageNr === 0` and Next button disables when `pageNr >= Math.floor(arr.length / 5)`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48544971/3297291) for an explanation to a similar question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let 
  arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],
  size = 5,
  current = 1;

function handleClick(go){
  if(go === "prev" && current > 1){
    current--
  }
  else if(go === "next" && current >= 1 && current < arr.length/size){
    current++
  }
  console.log(getNewArr())
}

function getNewArr(){
  return arr.slice(size*current - size, size*current)
}
```

```html
<button onclick=handleClick("prev")>prev</button>
<button onclick=handleClick("next")>next</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take an index and a size for the wanted elements ans dlice the array.

```js
const
    data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
    show = array => document.getElementById('items').innerHTML = array.join(' '),
    next = () => {
        index += size;
        while (index >= data.length) index -= size;
        show(data.slice(index, index + size));
    },
    prev = () => {
        index -= size;
        while (index < 0) index += size;
        show(data.slice(index, index + size));
    },
    size = 5;

let index = 0;

document.getElementById('bprev').addEventListener('click', prev);
document.getElementById('bnext').addEventListener('click', next);

show(data.slice(index, index + size));
```

```html
<button id="bprev">prev</button> <span id="items"></span> <button id="bnext">next</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

For now I am just creating a demo with the hardcoded `pageNumber` in `next` and `previous` click events but you can make it dynamic based on the array size.

**Working Demo :**

```js
// Input array
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

// Method which returns the updated array elements based on the pageSize and pageNumber.
const paginate = (array, pageSize, pageNumber) => {
  return array.slice((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize, pageNumber * pageSize);
}

// On load initializing 5 elements.
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML =  paginate(arr, 5, 1);

// Next button click event
document.getElementById('next').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML =  paginate(arr, 5, 2);
};

// previous button click event
document.getElementById('previous').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML =  paginate(arr, 5, 1);
};
```

```html
<button id="previous">Previous</button>
<span id="content"></span>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```